# python 3.11.2 | prodia-api_key

Tags: python, api-key

I wanted to send a request to prodia using my api key, but my code doesn't work.

I added a couple of lines to output the job id immediately, but for some reason it doesn't work

```
import requests

url = "https://api.prodia.com/v1/job"

payload = {
    "model": "anythingv3_0-pruned.ckpt [2700c435]",
    "prompt": "Cat",
    "negative_prompt": "Dogs",
    "steps": 25,
    "cfg_scale": 7,
    "seed": -1,
    "sampler": "DPM++ 2M Karras"
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "X-Prodia-Key": "API_KEY"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
job_id = data["job_id"]

print(response.text)

print(f"https://api.prodia.com/v1/job/{job_id}")
```

problems :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Generation_bot\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = response.json()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I guess that's work like this

```
https://api.prodia.com/v1/job/{job_id}
```

Comment: Did you check if the response was valid?

Comment: Generated right (200) but link don't work